# Why http request with Guzzle doesn't work?

Tags: php, firebase, http-post, google-cloud-functions, guzzle6

I'm developing a website with [Laravel 5.7](http://laravel.com/docs/5.7) that has a registration form. When the form is submitted, its params are used to create another user via API.

These API have a `.cloudfunctions.net` endpoint and the web application is developed using Angular + Firebase.

When I make a [GuzzleHttp](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable) request to that endpoint, I receive back an HTML response: the google account login page.

The strange thing is that when I run the corresponding cURL command from my vagrant console, or I run the same request with Postman, it returns me a correct json response.

This is a cURL example command:

```
curl -d '{DATA}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u test:test -X POST https://{endpoint}.cloudfunctions.net/api/{function}
```

And this is my `ApiManager` class in Laravel project:

```
namespace App\Utils;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

/**
 * API Manager class.
 */
class ApiManager
{
    protected $client;

    protected $params;

    protected $body;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setupClient();
    }

    /**
     * Setup GuzzleHttp client.
     * @return void
     */
    private function setupClient()
    {
        $this->client = new Client([
          'base_uri' => env('REMOTE_ENDPOINT'),
          'auth' => [env('REMOTE_USERNAME'), env('REMOTE_PASSWORD')],
          'headers' => [
              'Accept' => 'application/json'
          ],
          'strict' => true
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Setup request body as json.
     * http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupBody($params)
    {
        $this->body = [
            'debug' => env('GUZZLE_DEBUG', false),
            'json' => $params
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Decode raw json body to associative array
     *
     * @param mixed $response
     * @return void
     */
    protected function getResponseBody($response)
    {
        $body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        if ($body != null && array_key_exists('error', $body)) {
            return $body['error'];
        }

        return $body;
    }

    /**
     * Create user request.
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return mixed $response
     */
    public function createUser($params)
    {
        $this->setupBody($params);

        $response = $this->client->request('POST', '/create-user', $this->body);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $this->getResponseBody($response);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Update user request.
     *
     * @param array $params
     * @return mixed $response
     */
    public function updateUser($params)
    {
        $this->setupBody($params);

        $response = $this->client->request('POST', '/update-user', $this->body);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $this->getResponseBody($response);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me find why Guzzle returns the Google account login page, while Postman or cURL from command line work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: cuzzle is good, it converts guzzle into curl requests, great for debugging https://github.com/namshi/cuzzle

Comment: can you get `env()` values on `ApiManager`?

Comment: yes, everything is setted correctly